# how to make background transparent without affecting text in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am setting opacity to screen background.But my two buttons are affecting due to opacity added to background image.
please give me solution to remove opacity to the buttons.`

```
    android:background="@drawable/handicart_back_1"
        android:alpha="0.7">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
            android:alpha="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SIGNUP"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="107dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting alpha for the RelativeLayout not background only.
I only know a programmatically solution:

1. get the BackgroundDrawable of Layout:

   ```
     Drawable d = relativeLayout.getBackground()
   ```
2. Set Alpha for Drawable:

   ```
     d.setAlpha(0.7f)
   ```
3. Maybe set Background again (Don't know if required)

   ```
   relativeLayout.setBackground(d)
   ```
4. remove alpha from relativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` or `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` (both doing something a little different)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this trick. We will set alpha to the image which acts like background picture by its width and height settings as match parent. And do not forget to place it before your buttons to lets it underlay these buttons.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/pic" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LOGIN" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:text="SIGNUP" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```